# How do I target non-immediate parent of class

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(".less").click(function(){    
    $(".myblurb").css('height', '220'); 
});
```

In a setup like this.

```
<div class="myblurb">
<p>Some text</p>
<p>A <a href="#" class="less">link</a></p>
</div>
```

I have 3 or more different "myblurb" DIVs on a page and sometimes the "less" link may be nested further down inside the "myblurb" DIV.

How do I target this specific "myblurb" only?  It may or may not be an immediate parent of the "less" link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to get the first ancestor in DOM tree.

```
$(".less").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".myblurb").css('height', '220');
});
```

```js
$(".less").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".myblurb").css('height', '220');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myblurb">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>A <a href="#" class="less">link</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed...it does just what I was trying to do but I didn't realize it existed.  Here is the reference page for anyone looking into it.  THANKS! https://api.jquery.com/closest/